# SQL LIMIT совместно с оператором or

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите пожалуйста как составить запрос, что бы 'вытащить' определённое количество строк. Делаю пагинацию. Есть переписка пользователя с пользователем, в базе таблица выглядит так id_from, id_to, text, date, flag.

Запросом

`$sqlSelect = "SELECT id_from, id_to, text, date, flag FROM messages WHERE id_from = '$id_from' and id_to = '$id_to' OR id_from = '$id_to' and id_to = '$id_from' ";`

я 'вытаскиваю' многомерный массив переписки пользователей и с этим все ок. Столкнулся с проблемой вывода при использовании оператора LIMIT, при установке значения **LIMIT n**, выводятся сообщения только одного пользователя, при установке значения **LIMIT n, n**, вообще происходит путаница. Я так понимаю что проблема в том что я использую оператор OR, и выбор идет до этого оператора, а если значений не хватает, то выбор продолжается после оператора. Как организовать запрос, что бы была 'корректная' лимитированная выдача сообщения, последовательно. Организовывал запрос в скобках, ничего не меняется.

Comment: Нет. Проблема в том, что в запросе не указана сортировка. Добавьте правильный ORDER BY (по которому записи уникальны - например, ORDER BY date) - и проблема сама рассосётся.

Comment: Благодарю, так выводится корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Akina как всегда отвечает правильно, но не оформляет ответом.

Поясню немного детальнее.

В стандарте SQL и документации всех известных мне серверов сказано, что при использовании `LIMIT` без `ORDER BY` результат не предсказуем, потому что порядок будет тот, что удобен серверу.

А при использовании `OR` в `WHERE`, при наличии индексов, серверу удобнее преобразовать запрос в следующий вид:

```
SELECT id_from, id_to, text, date, flag FROM messages
WHERE id_from = '$id_from' and id_to = '$id_to' -- Первая половина OR
UNION
SELECT id_from, id_to, text, date, flag FROM messages
WHERE id_from = '$id_to' and id_to = '$id_from' -- Вторая половина OR
```

то есть сначала все сообщения в одну сторону, потом в обратную

Так как в первой части достаточно данных, до второй мы не доходим.

Решение - фиксировать порядок записей явным указанием `ORDER BY`